# JS скрипт маски чисел

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Помогите реализовать следующую задачу на JS.

Есть поле *input*. В него можно вводить только числа. Нужно автоматически подставлять маску по следующим правилам

```
если 5 чисел: Z-ZZ-ZZ
если 6 чисел: ZZ-ZZ-ZZ
если 7 чисел: ZZZ-ZZ-ZZ
```

Comment: перехват события `onkeypress`

Answer (score 2):

Слушать событие "input". Брать содержание input и выкидывать всё, кроме цифр. Последовательность цифр форматировать: перевести в массив и вставить в нужных местах дефисы, как вариант.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("in");
function update() {
  var n = el.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') // оставить только цифры
    .split('').reverse(); // перевестив массив и развернуть
  if(n.length > 2) n.splice(2,0,'-');
  if(n.length > 5) n.splice(5,0,'-');
  el.value = n.reverse().join('');
}

el.addEventListener("input", update);
```

```html
<input id="in" type="text" placeholder="ZZZ-ZZ-ZZ">
```